# Undefined Variable in Derivative Class with Private Variable in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, undefined

I'm attempting to create a mysql query using OOP in PHP.  In the code below the class "database_disconnection" does not toss any errors or notices, however the last class "database_query" gives me a notice that $database_handle is undefined.  I have no idea what's causing this as I created the database_query class as a derivative class of database_connection, which include the $database_handle variable as private.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Instantiating the objects:

```
 include("includes/database_classes.php");

 new database_connection;
 new database_query('SELECT * FROM users');
```

and the classes:

```
<?php
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
class database_connection
{

    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $database = 'assistant';    
    private $database_handle;

    function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            $database_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        }

        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e ->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
class database_disconnection extends database_connection
{
    function disconnect()
    {
        $database_handle = null;
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
class database_query extends database_connection
{
    private $mysql_statement;

    function __construct( $mysql_statement )
    {
        $this->mysql_statement = $mysql_statement;

        foreach($database_handle->query("$mysql_statement") as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }

}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
?>
```

Comment: `$database_handle` is a local-scoped variable; `$this->database_handle` would refer to the class property

Comment: Also, private attributes are not available to child classes.

Comment: Dan08 - thank you, I confused private and protected!  Thanks for the note.  However using the protected access restriction which does allow derivitives still is not working.  Your comment in combination with Mark Baker's worked to take it off notice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `database_query` constructor, you're attempting to use `$database_handle` before initializing it. If you notice, you only initialize in the `connect` function of your parent class (`database_connection`).

Either call `connect` before trying to refer to it, or initialize it in the parent's constructor, and call it (`parent::__construct();`).